# Conditioning a linear operator in order to be diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, diagonalization

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^{4} \to \mathbb{R}^{4} $ be a linear operator such $$T(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4})=(0,ax_{1},bx_{2},cx_{3}).$$

Find the conditions  over the numbers $a,b$ and $c$ which make $T$ diagonalizable.

I try to analyze the behavior of $T$ by calculating $[T]_{\beta}$ when $\beta$ is the canonical basis for $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ but this is \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0\\a&0&0&0\\0&b&0&0\\0&0&c&0\end{bmatrix}
 So the characteristical polynomial is zero since $det([T]_{\beta})=0$ so which values for $a,b$ and $c$ work ? Thanks

Comment: This matrix is not diagonalizable: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize+{{0,0,0,0},{a,0,0,0},{0,b,0,0},{0,0,c,0}}

Comment: I know, so the exercise is wrong?

Comment: We can say that that there are no values of $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: Great! So I mean a solution for the exercise will be to justify why such values doesnt exist?

Comment: @EmilioNovati $a = b = c = 0$ certainly makes the matrix diagonalizable.

Comment: Yes, but I suppose that the OP does not want $T=0$ :)

Comment: @Cos:  Rememeber that a matrix  is diagonalizable iff  the roots of its minimal polynomial have all algebraic multiplicity $=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = [T]_\beta$.  Then the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
$$
\det(A - t I) =
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
-t & 0 & 0 & 0\\
a & -t & 0 & 0\\
0 & b & -t & 0\\
0 & 0 & c & -t
\end{bmatrix}
= t^4
$$
so $0$ is an eigenvalue of algebraic multiplicity $4$.  In order for $A$ to be diagonalizble, this means that the eigenspace of $\lambda = 0$, i.e., the null space of $A$, must have dimension $4$.  This can only occur when $A$ is the zero matrix, that is, $a = b = c = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

[See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_%28linear_algebra%29#Applications), that is:

> a matrix is diagonalizable if and only if  its minimal polynomial factors  into distinct linear factors.

We have:
$A\ne 0 \qquad A^2 \ne 0 \qquad A^3 \ne 0 \qquad A^4=0$

so the minimal polynomial of the matrix $A$ is $A^4$ that has four identical factors.